# What mean of the word façade?

Tags: word-meaning

When I read a book, I have a incognizant word in the book:

> When you set the frame, you set the bounds size and position. In general, you should regard the frame as a convenient façade and no more. Nevertheless, it is convenient!

This paragraph, whats mean of `façade` ? I query the dictionary, can not find the explantion of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**façade** is a loan word from French (hence the *cédille* under the 'c'), and is most commonly written in its unaccented form (*facade*) in English, which may explain why you couldn't find it in the dictionary.

A facade is the front of a building, but more broadly it can be defined as 'an outward appearance that is maintained to conceal a less pleasant or creditable reality', which is appropriate to the sentence you gave as an example of usage.

A quick google of the text shows that it's written in the context of iOS layers, and it states slightly earlier that a layer's frame is a purely derived property, which is calculated from various properties (bounds size and position). In other words, your 'frame' isn't actually a frame - outwardly it appears as one, but in reality it's simply calculated from the values you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the [cedilla mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%87) (the thing under the "c") you may find your definition.
When words which use this are used in English, it is dropped.

> **facade** - an outward appearance that is maintained to conceal a less pleasant or creditable reality.

It means the "face" or "surface" which is seen.